# How to select elements on the same level only

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Export Model</legend>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">
    <br>
    <button onclick="addCategory(this)" type="button">Add Category</button>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Category
            <button class="del-but" type="button">Remove</button></legend>
        <label for="Name">Name</label><input id="name" name="name" type="text" value=""><br>
        <button class="add-cat-but" onclick="addCategory(this)" type="button">Add SubCategory</button>
        <button class="add-chart-but" onclick="addChart(this)" type="button">Add Chart</button>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

I have some fieldsets where I want to add more inside of each other to build a tree of elements. My problem is that a "category" fieldset can only have another category or a chart.

So what I am trying to do is to remove the "Add chart" button when pressing "Add category". The buttons are at the same level inside the fieldset but cant figure it out how to stop the search there (it deletes button from lower levels).

Can someone help me?

Scripts:

function addCategory(btn) {

```
        var $addCategory = "<fieldset>";
        $addCategory += "<legend>Category " + removeButton + "</legend>";
        $addCategory += '@Html.Label("Name")';
        $addCategory += '@Html.TextBox("name")';
        $addCategory += "<br />";
        $addCategory += addCategoryButton;
        $addCategory += addChartButton;
        $addCategory += "</fieldset>";
        $(btn).parent().children().find(".add-chart-but").remove();
        $(btn).parent().append($addCategory);
        $(document).on("click", ".del-but", remove);

    }

    function addChart(btn) {
        var $addChart = "<fieldset>";
        $addChart += "<legend>Chart " + removeButton + "</legend>";
        $addChart += '@Html.Label("Name")';
        $addChart += '@Html.TextBox("name")';
        $addChart += "<br />";
        $addChart += addSerieButton;
        $addChart += addDetailButton;
        $addChart += "</fieldset>";
        $(btn).parent().append($addChart);
        $(document).on("click", ".del-but", remove);
    }

    function remove() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }
```

**Found a solution:**

Replaced:

```
$(btn).parent().children().find(".add-chart-but").remove();
```

with:

```
$(btn).siblings(".add-chart-but").remove();
```

Comment: what this refers to in your remove code

Comment: It's not the remove function. that one is to remove an entire fieldset. I was struggling in the addCategory function to remove the neiboring button

Answer (score 1):

Just insert `find()` selector to `children()`:

```
$(btn).parent().children().find(".add-chart-but").remove();
```

change to

```
$(btn).parent().children(".add-chart-but").remove();
```

Comment: It's not.
Read the [api.jquery.com/children/](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
`children()` searches one level only.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) ? It traverses up the DOM tree. It should also work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to remove the adjacent button

```
$(btn).next(".add-chart-but").remove();
```

right from the API documentation

> Gets the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements

Comment: does it stop at the same level or keeps searching down?

Comment: it will stop immediately after it finds the first match

Comment: that match could be a few lvls down. (It's not guaranteed to have a element at the same level as you can add multiple categories)

Comment: next will search on the same level until it finds a match.not sure if that was your concern